# Set datetimepicker value using hour and minute int Variables

Tags: c#, datetime, int, double

got a problem.
I want to convert two doubles to a time format (HH:mm)(2.5 equals to 02:30 for example).  I got a hour int variable and minute int variable. The problem is that I don't know what to do with them, I mean how I import them to the date time picker.
At the beginning the time is stored in a string in an array.

```
public {
    int hour = 5;
    int min =40;
    time.Value = new DateTime(hour, min);// ***this is a mistake***
}
```

**The outcome should be 05:40** in a datepicker

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862684/converting-from-decimal-degrees-to-degrees-minutes-seconds-tenths

Answer (score 3):

not sure about your requirement, but something like below,

```
time.Value = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);
```

Comment: I don't want to add the hours and the minutes to the datepicker. I want it to show only the time in the variables. Thanks a lot by the way...

Comment: @misha312 what is the difference between your answer and my answer? i'm getting current date and set hours and minutes. finally it will give you the value you want

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Date` can be replaced by the simpler `DateTime.Today`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer.

```
DetaTimePicker.Value = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 
                   DateTime.Now.Day, hour integer, minute integer, 0);
```

The zero is the minutes.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

SET time as 13:30

```
 DateTimePicker newDate = (DateTimePicker)rootcontrol;
 String format = "H:mm";
 DateTime dDate;
     try
      {
        DateTime.TryParseExact(answer, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDate);
       newDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        newDate.Value = dDate;
      }
       catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
     {
        newDate.Text = answer;
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR SET TIME:" + answer);
      }
```