# Given GPS coordinates in decimals, how can I convert them to degrees in python?

Tags: python, gps, degrees

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Convert DD to DMS in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579535/how-to-convert-dd-to-dms-in-python)
>   [Convert decimal coordinates to Degrees, Minutes & Seconds by c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187678/convert-decimal-coordinates-to-degrees-minutes-seconds-by-c-sharp)

How can I convert a pair of decimal coordinates to degrees, as seen below?

```
>>> s.GPSCoordinatesDec
[40.650166666666664, -73.78183333333334]
```

Comment: Was really hoping to see a "pythonic" example. I'm still learning the language and want to make sure things are done right. Thanks.

Comment: Those *are* degrees. Did you mean to convert the decimal fraction to minutes and seconds?

Answer (score -1):

[How to Convert DD to DMS in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579535/how-to-convert-dd-to-dms-in-python)